# Data inserted into the database is missing when fetching data using separate lambda

Tags: mysql, sql, aws-lambda, mysql-python, pymysql

I ran into this issue using AWS Lambda with API Gateway.

The workflow was that one lambda inserts an item into the database. Then another lambda fetches the list of items from DB.
The newly created item was missing from the initial fetch. But if the listing lambda is invoked again all items are fetched correctly (No idea why).

I defined the connection outside of the lambda handler (as recommended).
This issue was fixed by forcefully closing DB connections inside the lambda handler on all invocations. So now each lambda invocation creates a new connection.

I wanted to know why this is happening. Is the closing of the connection/cursor necessary?

Some code to give more clarity. The issue can be reproduced by using the below code. Consider each connection defined in the example being used in separate lambdas

```
def sample_code():
    # Create Connection 1 (//Lambda 1)
    conn_1 = get_connection()
    cursor_1 = get_cursor(conn_1)
    random_string = str(random.randint(1, 100))
    cursor_1.execute(SQL_INSERT, ("John", random_string))
    conn_1.commit()
    print(f"1. Inserted {('John', random_string)}")
    cursor_1.execute(SQL_GET)
    result = cursor_1.fetchall()
    print(f"1. All rows -> {result=}")
    
    # Create a new Connection/Cursor 2 (//Lambda 2)
    conn_2 = get_connection()
    cur_2 = get_cursor(conn_2)
    random_string = str(random.randint(1, 100))
    cur_2.execute(SQL_INSERT, ("Doe", random_string))
    conn_2.commit()
    print(f"2. Inserted {('Doe', random_string)}")
    cur_2.execute(SQL_GET)
    results = cur_2.fetchall()
    cur_2.close()
    conn_2.close()
    print(f"2. All rows -> {results=}")

    # Fetch results using Connection/Cursor 1. (Lambda 1)
    cursor_1.execute(SQL_GET)
    get_resp = cursor_1.fetchall()
    print(f"\n1. All rows {get_resp=}")
    
    # Create a new connection 3 (//Lambda 3)
    con3 = get_connection()
    cur_3 = get_cursor(con3)
    cur_3.execute(SQL_GET)
    results = cur_3.fetchall()
    print(f"\n3. All rows -> {results=}")
```

output

```
1. Inserted ('John', '75')
1. All rows -> result=((None, '75', 'John'),)
2. Inserted ('Doe', '66')
2. All rows -> results=((None, '75', 'John'), (None, '66', 'Doe'))

1. All rows get_resp=((None, '75', 'John'),)

3. All rows -> results=((None, '75', 'John'), (None, '66', 'Doe'))
```

My problem is the data inserted using connection 2 is missing when it is fetched using connection 1.

The database is MySQL and uses [PyMysql](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/) client.

Comment: 'when fetching data using separate lambda' - this all looks like one Lambda to me? Can you reproduce this using local code? Are you sure this is specific to Lambda? We need to see the rest of the code.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Consider each connection in the above example as a separate lambda.